# A lot of sentences not prepared to be translated on Post Flag History page

Tags: bug, status-review, flags, moderator-tools, localization

Below is the screenshot from one Post Flag History page on ruSO:

> [image]

There are many items don't prepared to be translatable:

- Post Flag History
- for
- Creation Date
- Creation User
- Type
- Deletion Date
- Deletion User
- Comment
- Result
- Initial Body
- Initial Title
- Initial Tags
- Edit Body
- Edit Title
- Rollback Title
- Post Locked
- Post Notice Added
- Post Unlocked
- Post Notice Removed
- Helpful
- Rollback to [{giud}]

There are obviously many other related strings that can't be found on a single post. The developers should know better what other strings could be there.